# password_hash vs performance

Tags: php, segurança, desempenho

Uma de minhas maiores preocupações quando estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação sempre foi a performance que ela teria, especialmente em servidores compartilhados, na qual maior parte dos meus clientes se concentra. Micro-otimizações são sempre bem vindas em meus sistemas, pois sigo a velha filosofia do ditado: de grão em grão, a galinha enche o papo.

Porém, comecei a focar recentemente na segurança dos sistemas, na qual sentia certa carência de atenção em um fator tão importante.

Sempre utilizei **sha1** e **md5** para fazer storage no banco de dados, mas recentemente vi uma matéria que falava que esta técnica não é mais recomendada, pois há possibilidade de duplicação e por ser muito fácil de "quebrar" ambas, por força bruta.

Conheci então a função `password_hash` do php, que seria a "nova" forma de armazenar estas informações no BD.

Porém, em meus testes, vi que esta função não está muito amigável para com a performance.

[image: comparativo de performance]
Na imagem acima, o indicador vermelho se refere ao script utilizando: `sha1(md5($senha))`, e o indicador azul utilizando `password_hash($senha, PASSWORD_DEFAULT, ['cost' => 12])`.

Notável queda de performance, chegando a quase **80%**.

Eu sei que a segurança é imprescindível, mas: Até que ponto a mesma deve interferir na performance — consequentemente experiência do usuário, que poderá ter um servidor mais lerdo?

Como colocar ambas na balança para manter o equilíbrio?

Comment: Como é uma opinião pessoal vou colocar aqui como comentário. Acredito que até o ponto em que o usuário não tenha que esperar vários segundos por uma resposta da página, não vejo problema algum em "prejudicar" a performance por um ganho na segurança. Você como "tester" pode ter esse _feeling_, se vc estiver se incomodando esperando o resultado do teste, pode ser que vc tenha ultrapassado o limite...

Comment: @KaduAmaral Pode ser que haja um "preconceito" instituído em mim, por sempre aplicar as micro-otimizações e vendo valores como porcentagens e não como resultados reais. Refletindo sobre seu comentário, percebi que, de fato, um aumento de 300ms no processamento, em apenas 2 atos (login e criação de conta) pode ser um preço barato a se pagar, em relação à segurança fornecida em troca.

Comment: Sim Daniel, já li um artigo também sobre essas micro-otimizações, e a conclusão do autor era que "a menos que você esteja criando um site como o Google que recebe milhões de requisições por minuto, não vale a pena o tempo gasto com essas otimizações, pelo ganho que elas oferecem."